# Regarding execution of functions after partial page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating a web page in which after reloading the page an ajax call is made to the server and display some data.There is a

```
$(document).ready( function(){.... some work.... });
```

In the same page there is a refresh button clicking which I want to reload just the ajax called data part.But here

```
  $(document).ready( function(){.... some work.... });
```

This is not executing.

Is there any way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Write your ajax call in some function Like this

```
function fnFetchData(){
 // Ajax Call
}
```

And Call this function from

```
$(document).ready({
  fnFetchData();
});
```

And Call ths function from your Refresh Button